# 2 queen, $5\times 5$ chess board problem

Tags: problem-solving, chessboard

Prove the following:
In $5\times 5$ chess board the least amount of queens you need in order to threaten on each square is 3.
(Square threat: the queens threatens on each square in the diagonals,row and column from the queens position).

I just need to show that you can't threaten the whole $5\times 5$ board with 2 queens.

Comment: This is also called the [domination problem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_chess_problem#Domination_problems). See whether this helps you: dspace.library.uvic.ca:8080/bitstream/handle/1828/2415/DM-408-IR.pdf.

Comment: Hint: How many squares can a single queen threaten?

Comment: Up to 17 so it doesn't help pretty much,

Comment: @Itay.V OK, counting the largest diagonals, right? How many of those are there?

Comment: @shardulc 1 queen can can threat 15 square while the other will threat 17 what you need to show is that the intersection will be greater then 7. Now the whole point is to show  |A+B| = |A|+|B|-|AandB|<25 for all A and B

Answer (score 0):

A case analysis is sufficient. Let the top left corner by black.

You need both a B queen and a W queen (we can see this by counting their max range of W and B).

If the W queen is on the boundary, then 3 W boundary squares remain to be covered and their position makes it impossible to be covered by a B queen.

If the W queen is not on the boundary, then 2 W squares on the same column must be covered by a B queen (which must be in that column) and now you can see that covering all B squares is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can place at most 1 queen in the center, and then for symmetry of rotating and mirroring, you should have at least 1 queen on A1, A2, or B2.

Now allow that the other one can also be placed outside of the center.

Then a simple case analysis.. (Finding e.g. triplets that can't be covered)

Comment: You'll just show that case where queen is in the middle, and ? How do you know that the right case can't be when there is no queen in the middle ?

Comment: The 'in the middle' part is needed to demonstrate that there is one queen in the top left 2x2 , but indeed, my answer is wrong. C1,C2 are also options.